# sqlite reuse of unique/primary keys that are not in use anymore

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to know if :

1. Is it OK to reuse unique entry at a table if the old table line that contains the value being re-used has been removed: That means that at any given time the value is unique, however, at history, same value may have been used....
2. Same with the case of "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX" - Again: At any given time, value is unique, however, at history, same value was used
3. Same condition for PRIMARY KEY

Comment: That is absolutely a valid case.If the primary key is a also foreign from another table, that will happen all the time.

Answer (score 1):

A unique index/constraint is a requirement on the values inside a table.  This does not apply to deleted rows.

You may have issues if you attempt to make changes *within a transaction*.  For instance, the following generates an unique-constraint error:

```
create table t (x int unique);

insert into t(x) values (1), (2);

update t
    set x = x + 1;
```

Comment: My fear was around indexing. After adding a line, some rows are indexed, to enable fast access. Indexing use structures outside of the table. I was wondering if after deleting a line, and adding a different line in which there is a similar value in a unique/indexed row, there could be a problem due to the indexing.